# Apache Flink - can't compile KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness with Int or Long generic parameters

Tags: scala, apache-flink

The bellow mentioned Apache Flink test code doesn't compile in Scala when I want to use KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[K, IN, OUT] with Int or Long as the key (K) parameter. The same code can be compiled with generic parameters of type STRING, INTEGER or java.lang.Long:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.Types
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.KeyedProcessOperator
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.junit.Test

case class TaxiRide(rideId: Int)

class RideKeySelector extends KeySelector[TaxiRide, Int] {
  override def getKey(in: TaxiRide): Int = in.rideId
}

class RideTests {
  private def setupHarness(function: KeyedProcessFunction[Int, TaxiRide, Int]): KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[Int, TaxiRide, Int] = {
    val operator: KeyedProcessOperator[Int, TaxiRide, Int] = new KeyedProcessOperator(function)

    val testHarness: KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[Int, TaxiRide, Int] =
      new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(operator, new RideKeySelector(), Types.INT)

    testHarness.setup()
    testHarness.open()

    testHarness
  }
}
```

**Build error:**

```
type mismatch;
 found   : org.example.RideKeySelector
 required: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[org.example.TaxiRide,Int]
      new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(operator, new RideKeySelector(), Types.INT)
```

I created the project from the following Maven archetype:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-quickstart-scala</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I added the following test dependencies to pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-test-utils_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>    
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>    
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>    
        <scope>test</scope>    
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried to replace the key selector with a lambda:

```
val testHarness = new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(operator, (ride: TaxiRide) => ride.rideId, Types.INT)
```

The **build error** changes to:

```
overloaded method constructor KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness with alternatives:
  (x$1: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator[IN,OUT],x$2: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[IN,K],x$3: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K],x$4: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.testutils.MockEnvironment)org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[K,IN,OUT] <and>
  (x$1: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator[IN,OUT],x$2: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[IN,K],x$3: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K])org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[K,IN,OUT] <and>
  (x$1: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorFactory[OUT],x$2: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[IN,K],x$3: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K])org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[K,IN,OUT] <and>
  (x$1: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorFactory[OUT],x$2: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[IN,K],x$3: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K],x$4: Int,x$5: Int,x$6: Int)org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[K,IN,OUT] <and>
  (x$1: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator[IN,OUT],x$2: org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector[IN,K],x$3: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K],x$4: Int,x$5: Int,x$6: Int)org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[K,IN,OUT]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.KeyedProcessOperator[Int,org.example.TaxiRide,Int], org.example.TaxiRide => Integer, org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[Integer])
     testHarness = new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(operator, (ride: TaxiRide) => ride.rideId, Types.INT)
```

It looks like that it cannot accept Scala types, why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

Parameterised types are connected to a concept called `type variance`.

When you have a `Wrapper` which take a type parameter `A`, then your `Wrapper` can either be `invariant`, `covariant` or `contravariant` with respective to type `A`.

`invariant` :: types `Wrapper[A]` and `Wrapper[B]` simply do not care about type relationship between `A` and `B`. There will simply be no relation between `Wrapper[A]` and `Wrapper[B]`.

`covariant` :: given a type `B` which is sub type of another type `A` (read as `B extends A`), then `Wrapper[B]` will also be a sub type of `Wrapper[A]` (read as `Wrapper[B] extends Wrapper[A]`).

`contravariant` :: given a type `B` which is sub type of another type `A` (read as `B extends A`), then `Wrapper[B]` will be a super type of `Wrapper[A]` (read as `Wrapper[A] extends Wrapper[B]`).

Java only allows `invariant` type parameters while Scala allows you to choose the `variance` as required using `Wrapper[A]` for `invariant`, `Wrapper[+A]` for `covariant` and `Wrapper[-A]` for `contravariant` relations.

So, for any paramterised type `Wrapper[T]` implemented in Java, `Wrapper[A]` and `Wrapper[B]` will have no relation, irrespective of any existing relationship between `A` and `B`.

As `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` is implemented in Java, it is `invariant` with respect to relationship between `RideKeySelector` and `KeySelector[TaxiRide, Int]`.

While you don't need to worry about `variance` in many cases when you are dealing with `invariant` type parameter at `covariant` places and things just work coincidently but they almost never work when dealing with `invariant` type parameter at `contravariant` place.

But when it works you have to remember that it's just a coincidence that the type was not used at any `contravariant` places, and you should not rely on it working, as the developers never intended it. It might change with one extra addition of a `contravariant` used to the class in future releases.

This is exactly the case here, the second type parameter `In` of `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<K, IN, OUT>` is used at naturally `contravariant` places in class `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness`.

As for the overloaded method error, that is because the constructor for `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<K, IN, OUT>` wants a `KeySelector<IN, K>`. Thus `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<Int, TaxiRide, Int>` wants a `KeySelector<TaxiRide, Int>` and not a `scala.Function1[TaxiRide, Int]` as you are providing it in following line,

```scala
val testHarness = 
  new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(
    operator,
   (ride: TaxiRide) => ride.rideId,
   Types.INT
)
```

Now, You just need to provide the proper instances.

```scala
val rideKeySelector = new KeySelector[TaxiRide, Int] {
  @throws(classOf[Exception])
  override def getKey(value: TaxiRide): Int = value.rideId
}

val testHarness = 
  new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(
    operator,
   rideKeySelector,
   Types.INT
)
```

I will additionally suggest that you just simply drop the usage of `Int` (and simply use `java.lang.Integer`) when dealing with type intensive Java libraries. Interactions between Scala's `Int` and Java's `int` and `Integer` have enough intricacies to write a full book.

Comment: your last code snippet doesn't compile neither, it is actually very similar to my class RideKeySelector. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea which dependency this `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness ` is coming from in your code. It is not present in any of the 4 dependecies provided by you. Also, this is supposed to give you more context about how to solve the specific problems which you described.

Comment: `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` is from `flink-streaming-java_2.11`.
Other not mentioned parts are from the archetype `flink-quickstart-scala`.
The problematic part based on your great description is probably this `TypeInformation<Integer> intType = Types.INT;`
I would expect that there should be a Scala counterpart for the `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` in `flink-streaming-scala_2.11` or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @sarveshseri, however, I would put it into other words.

The custom object that you are passing breaks Type check, as @sarveshseri stated, the type can vary so Java doesn't like what is going on.

You must create Tupples in your pipe consisting of primitive types like Integer, String, and Long. I don't know the complete list you need to check it from the documentation. In this case, you can create complex Tupples to pass the data you need, parsing before the function that you are testing. You need to do this if you don't want to parse the object again and again in the function and in the key-selector.

Here is a key-selector example with the idea, you need to figure it out in your case:

```
val keySelector = new KeySelector[((String, Long), String), String] {
      @throws(classOf[Exception])
      override def getKey(value: ((String, Long), String)): String = value._1._1
    }
```

Then, your stream operator can be like this:

```
    harness = new KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness[String, ((String, Long), String), String](new KeyedProcessOperator(processFunction), keySelector, Types.STRING)
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers.